# Trouble with duplicate key on nested query oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, duplicates

I'm having a bit of trouble with my query, I keep getting duplicate keys. And I can't see why, it's the same info an account, amount and amount_trans.

Any and all help would be greatly apriciated. :)

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    a1.account,
    a2.amount,
    a3.amount_trans
    FROM 
    product_agreement a1,
    (
    SELECT
        transfers.account,
        transfers.amount
    FROM
        transfers,
        transfers_table
    WHERE
        transfers_table.transfer_id = transfers.transfer_id_last
        AND transfers_table.active_indicator = 1
        AND transfers.amount <= 0
    ) a2,
    (
    SELECT 
    trans_info.account,
        COUNT(trans_info.account) amount_trans,
        MAX(trans_info.date) siste_transe,
        MIN(trans_info.date) forste_transe,
        MAX(trans_info.last_info_id) last_info_id
    FROM
        trans_info
    WHERE
        trans_info.date >= TO_DATE(add_months(SYSDATE,-24),'DD.MM.YYYY')
    GROUP BY
        trans_info.account
    ) a3
    WHERE 
    (
    a1.type_kode = 'ACTIVE'
    AND a1.finished IS NULL
    AND a1.completed IS NULL
    )
    AND
    a2.account = a1.account
    AND
    a2.account = a3.account
    AND a3.amount_trans <= 5;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should switch to 'modern' explicit `join` syntax, most people find it easier to read.

Comment: Check which of a1 or a2 has the duplicate keys. a3 is safe.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was that A2 had duplicate keys. I had to go through the data as there where some inconsistencies in the data. Thanks for all the help. :)